# D3 scatter plot transform symbols

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, d3.js

I am looking for sample code how to load a custom scatter plot symbol (an arrow as in the screen shot) and transform it (rotate / scale) at each scatter. Is it possible with the d3 library at all?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To make the symbol, you can use something like the [SVGPathEditor](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/) to generate a path for your symbol.

Afterward, rotate as needed with`rotate()` in the `translate` attribute.

```
svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(data)
    .join("path")
      .attr("transform", d => `translate(${x(d.x)},${y(d.y)}) rotate(45)`)
      .attr("d", YOUR_SVG_PATH_HERE)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out!